# Why can I not install torch == 1.4.0?

Tags: python, anaconda, torch, virtual-environment, torchvision

I create a virtual environment on anaconda, the version of python is 3.6 that is recommended, and I want to install torch == 1.4.0. But it's always failed. I tried other versions of python, like python 3.7, it is still a failure. The following is the error message. Can anyone help me to solve it? Thanks in advance.

```
pip install torch==1.4.0


ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.4.0 (from versions: 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0
```

Comment: What is the output of `pip -V`  ?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @Jérôme where did you get that information. Python3 is supported [even in the very first release](https://pypi.org/project/torch/0.3.0.post4/#files)